# Django template forloopcounter value is not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The List as follows. Here forloopcounter value is not working. How to fix? Please let me know your views. Please note: static index value is working, but dynamic index value is not working (forloopcounter)

```
value = [
    {
        "pk": 1,
        "Rate": [
            {
                "one": "one1"
            },
            {
                "two": "two1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "pk": 2,
        "Rate": [
            {
                "one": "one2"
            },
            {
                "two": "two2"
            }
        ]
    }
]


{% for i in value %}

{{i.Rate.forloopcounter.one}} # here forloopcounter value is not working
{{i.Rate.0.one}} # This is working properly. But i need dynamic index

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why would this work? There is no key `forloopcounter` in your dictionary.

Comment: Yes, Rate is the first key. But why would you think `forloopcounter` would work as the index into the list?

Comment: the concept here is forloopcounter value is getting from the main loop i.e. value, then using that I want to get value from the Rate List. Do you think its fishy ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're using what you think you're using.

```
{% for i in dict %}
    {{forloop.counter}}
```

`forloop.counter` increments on each iteration through your dictionary. forloopcounter is not a key in your dictionary, which is why your code doesn't work.